# Building a website ready algorithmic questionnaire

Tags: algorithm

Apologies if my question seems basic. Thank you in anticipation of your help.

I am currently building a questionnaire (on paper) which ultimately I want to be web based, with different outputs provided depending on each answer provided to the questions on the questionnaire.

For example:

Question 1: Do you prefer 1,2 or 3? 
Question 2: Are you 4, 5, or 6?
Question 3: Have you 7, 8, or 9?

Answer 1: If 1, suggest A, if 2, suggest B, if 3, suggest C.
Answer 2: If 4, suggest C, if 5, suggest nothing, if 6 suggest D
Answer 3: If 7, suggest A, if 8, suggest B, if 9, suggest nothing

So for example, If my answers are respectively 1, 5, and 7, then the output will be: A

If my answers are: 3, 4 and 6 then the output will be: C, D, A

At the moment I just want to build this questionnaire. Subsequently, I would like to then be able to add this questionnaire into my website (yet to be built).

Any ideas on how I can approach this? When I google the issue I'm just provided with a host of free online questionnaire tools which don't actually analyse the answers provided in the manner I would like.

Thank you

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. It also may not be completely a programming question because you may be able to accomplish the same goal using Google Forms or something similar. Can you rephrase the question to be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I would simple use some javascript to accomplish this. Something like this might work (it's probably more idea than actuall code but it works

```js
(function(){
  
 var dic = [ {"question":"Do you prefer 1,2,3", "answer": {1:"A",2:"B",3:"C"}}, 
             {"question":"Are you 4, 5, or 6", "answer": {4:"C",5:"nothing",6:"D"}},
             {"question":"Have you 7, 8, or 9", "answer": {7:"A",8:"B",9:"nothing"}} 
           ];

  // create questions
  var html = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < dic.length; i++) {    
    html += "<label for='first'>"+dic[i].question+" </label><input type='text' id='"+i+"' class='question' /><br>"
  }
  
  html += "<input type='button' value='submit' id='submit'/>";
  document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = html;
  
  // create answers
  document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var html = "";
    inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('question');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if(inputs[i].value != "") html += 'For "'+dic[inputs[i].id].question+'" we suggest: "'+ dic[inputs[i].id].answer[inputs[i].value]+'"<br>';
      else html += 'For "'+dic[inputs[i].id].question+'" please add an answer<br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("answers").innerHTML = html;
  });
  
})();
```

```html
<div id="questions"></div>
<div id="answers"></div>
```